# Order of Execution in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I can't understand the execution of the JavaScript code. After the function greet, the first two function declarations are executed:

```
function greet(myName) {
    var myAlertString = "Hello " + myName ; // Local variable
    function doAlert() {
        alert(myAlertString);
    }
    doAlert();
}

greet("Smak"); // will alert "Hello Smak"    

var greetSam = greet("Sam"); // greetKitty is now a function
greetSam(); // will alert "Hello Sam"

var greetKitty = greet("Kitty"); // greetKitty is now a function
greetKitty(); // will alert "Hello Kitty"

var greetMax = greet("Max"); // greetMax is now a function
greetMax(); // will alert "Hello Max"

greetKitty(); // will alert "Hello Kitty"
```

Why there is no pop-up for Kitty and Max?

I got the correct answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/QHN6T/13/

Comment: Is that some kind of spam or are you just unable to type "jsfiddle"?

Comment: Right now `greet()` invokes its inner function and returns its result. It does not return the function. Therefore, `greet("Smak")` will indeed alert immediately, and your further assumptions are wrong.

Comment: In your first fiddle, the `return` is missing. Hence the error.

Comment: Why do you have a different code in the fiddle and here ?

Comment: You could easily debug and see your error by using the browser's JavaScript/Error Console which says: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Comment: Are you saying that you figured out the problem and you're linking to the code that works? If you resolved the problem, you should post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted rather than linking to a solution from the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
var greetSam = greet("Sam"); // greetKitty is now a function
```

does *not* return a function. It returns the result of calling `alert()`, which is `undefined`. The next line:

```
greetSam(); // will alert "Hello Sam"
```

generates an error and stops the script.

If you change `greet` to return `doAlert` instead of `doAlert()`, then it will return a function. Unfortunately, then the first call:

```
greet("Smak");
```

will no longer generate an alert for `"Smak"`. You would have to write:

```
greet("Smak")();
```

Comment: @SubhrashisDas, you forgot to remove the parentheses after `doAlert` in that fiddle. `greet()` is still not returning a function.

Comment: @Ted Hopp I did it correctly, but why it is not Working. Look  http://jsfiddle.net/QHN6T/10 and only Smak is working not other.

Comment: @Frederic Hamidi. Please update jsfiddle and please comment the link of the correct approach.

Comment: @SubhrashisDas, please read this answer (and the other one by aefxx) one more time. Try to understand what they say about `return doAlert()` being different from `return doAlert`. Then apply that knowledge to your code.

Comment: @SubhrashisDas - I looked at your jsfiddle. The code on line 7 should be changed from `return doAlert();` to `return doAlert;` (without the parentheses). The reason you only see `Smak` is because when `greet("Smak")` is called, it generates the alert and then returns `undefined`. Since line 10 is actually `greet("Smak")();`, the second parentheses cause an error (because `undefined` is not a function) and the script stops. Change line 7 and all should be well.

Answer (score 5):

You've got an error with one of your assignments, namely:

```
var greetSam = greet("Sam"); // greetKitty is now a function
```

Your assumption is wrong. `greetSam` does not return a `function`, it returns `undefined`. Hence the call `greetSam()` a line further down produces a `TypeError: greetSam is not a function`.

Correctly written:

```
...
    doAlert();
    return doAlert;
}
```

Comment: It's not working for all look http://jsfiddle.net/QHN6T/12/ . Otherwise please update jsfiddle and give me the solution.

Comment: Nope, I won't fiddle with your fiddle. Go fiddle yourself.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, I just want that all the pop-up in the web page. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you have to replace

`return doAlert();`

with `return doAlert;`. The difference between the two is that the first version returns whatever `doAlert` returns, while the second returns a *function* that can be called later (a so-called *closure*), which is what you have intended. It has nothing to do with the order of execution.